# Don't understand results from solving easy polynomial equations

Tags: equation-solving, polynomials

I am alarmed by the behavior of *Mathematica* (9.0) when given the following simple set of equations to solve:

```
eq = {1 + x^3 - 5*x*y + y^3 == 0, 
      3 - 5*x*y + ((1 + I*Sqrt[3])*(-5*x + 3*y^2))/2 == 0}
```

`Solve[eq]` gives the 4 solutions correctly.
`Solve[eq,{x,y}]` results in the message

> Roots::neq: 0 is expected to be a polynomial in the variable x.
>
> Solve::svars: Equations may not give solutions for all "solve" variables.

and gives spurious solutions such as `{y -> (-I/2)*(-I + Sqrt[3])}`,
in addition to the correct ones.

How can I suppress / correct this strange behavior?

Comment: I formatted your answer. Please learn how to do it yourself [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/formatting). I also removed the bug tag, until it is confirmed as a bug

Comment: Also, I cannot reproduce the problem on my machine (MMA 10.2 on Ubuntu). Does the problem persist when you use a fresh kernel? (that is, if you restart the kernel, and only run the commands here)?

Comment: Both work fine for me, giving the same answer, on 10.2 on Mac OS X.  Reduce works as well.

Comment: [tag:bugs] is reserved until it is confirmed by the community or [WRI](http://www.wolfram.com/). I can reproduce this on 8.0.1 and 9.0.1, but not on 10.0.2. So, I think its fixed.

Comment: As a workaround you can eliminate elements of the solution that don' t include both variables: `Solve[eq, {x, y}] // Select[#, Length[#] == 2 &] &`

Answer (score 2):

This is not an answer but an extended comment.

On MMA V8.0.1, note the following:

```
eq = {1 + x^3 - 5*x*y + y^3 == 0,
  3 - 5*x*y + ((1 + I*Sqrt[3])*(-5*x + 3*y^2))/2 == 0};

sol = eq /. First@Solve[eq, {x, y}] // Expand
(* {2 + (5 x)/2 + 5/2 I Sqrt[3] x + x^3 == 0, True} *)
```

Then,

```
xsols = Solve[First@sol, x]
(* {   {x -> I (I + Sqrt[3])}
     , {x -> 1/2 (1 - I Sqrt[3] - I Sqrt[4 + 4 I Sqrt[3]])}
     , {x -> 1/2 (1 - I Sqrt[3] + I Sqrt[4 + 4 I Sqrt[3]])}   }  *)
```

and

```
xsols2 = First /@ Solve[eq, {x, y}][[2 ;; 4]];
Flatten@xsols === xsols2
(* True *)
```

In other words, it's not really finding spurious solutions. It's more like it's trying to do too much work.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the comments.

A robust workaround seems to be to use `Solve[Reduce[system], ...]` in place of `Solve[system, ...]`.

I am still surprised that such a basic bug is still present in *Mathematica* 9.0.

Comment: @blochwave "Thanks" appears to be incidental to the "robust workaround" given herein.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard you're right, mea culpa!